# Build and run ASP.NET 4.5 on OSX using Sublime or Atom text editors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, macos

I would like to build and run an existing ASP.NET **(v4.5)** application on OSX. While I am finding numerous working example of ASP.NET 5 apps running on OSX, I cannot find anything for older versions of ASP.NET? Am I missing something? Also, it would be perfect if there was a build plugin for Sublime or Atom for that method too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET 5 is a complete redesign to be open-source and available cross platform. Prior versions require Windows.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/aspnet.html